# Using find and grep in a specifc file in a specific directory

Tags: linux, unix, grep, find

I have the following directory structure:

```
./A1
./A2
./A3
./B
./C
```

In each one of the A* directories I have:

```
./A*/logs
./A*/test
```

in the logs directory I have:

```
./log-jan-1
./log-jan-2
./log-feb-1
```

How do I grep for a string in all January logs in the A directories?

I tried this, but it did not find the string although it is present in the log files:

```
find . -type d -name 'A*' print | xargs -n1 -I PATH grep string - PATH/logs/log-jan*
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please be more specific than "it did not work".

Comment: I corrected the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use

```
grep string ./A*/logs/log-jan*
```

?

Comment: It is more for my understanding, there are scenarios where you want to find specific directories/files based on some criteria then grep in them.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a typo, you should use `-print` (or `-print0`) instead of print.

But as `find` + `xargs` + `grep` constructs are hard to debug, you should test in sequence :

- `find . -type d -name 'A*' -print`
- `find . -type d -name 'A*' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I PATH echo grep string - PATH`

and finally :

```
find . -type d -name 'A*' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I PATH grep string - PATH/logs/log-jan*
```

In you use case, `-print` and `-print0` should give same results, but for having been burnt with `-print`, I always use `-print0` before `xargs`